# How to extract Latitude and longitude from ArcMap using Oracle as a database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, oracle-dbms

I'm facing a problem to convert my data on Oracle and I've already searched this topic on internet, but nothing gives me the elegant or simple solution. I have an ArcMap where connect to database using Oracle 10
my sample data look like this:

```
SELECT OBJECTID,GLOBALID,SHAPE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE OBJECTID='12345'

OBJECTID    |            GLOBALID                       |    SHAPE 
12345       | {911FA93E-820E-42B6-9A30-D8AE618AA650}    |SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(1, 1, 705750.7886, 9303735.2668, 705750.7886, 9303735.2668, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 2)
```

I know latitude and longitude are stored in column SHAPE in MY_TABLE.

What is the query syntax within Oracle to extract the latitude and longitude from SHAPE Column?  The output I want would look like this:

```
SHAPE |    LATITUDE |  LONGITUDE
..... |  -6.1153454 | 108.744888
```

Can anyone give me a way to do this?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: What about using SDE.ST_TRANSFORM? You need to convert the coordinates from the projected CRS that they're in to a geographic CRS.

Comment: It's been a while since Oracle 10.x was supported. Please always specify the ***exact*** versions of ArcGIS and Oracle in your questions. As Melita indicated, you need to use `SDE.ST_Transform` to deproject to 4326 (or whatever is appropriate to your projected CS), then `SDE.ST_X` for longitude and `SDE.ST_Y` for latitude.